# Random lottery numbers from macro to variable

Tags: stata

I have the following lottery numbers in a macro:

```
global lottery 6 9 4 32 98
```

How can I simulate a variable with `50` observations, where each observation is randomly obtained from the numbers stored in the macro?

The code below produces an error:

```
set obs 50
global lottery 6 9 4 32 98

g lot=$lottery
invalid '9' 
r(198);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two similar methods:

```
clear 
set obs 50 
set seed 2803 
local lottery 6 9 4 32 98

* method 1 
generate x1 = ceil(5 * runiform())

tabulate x1 

generate y1 = . 
forvalues j = 1/5 { 
    replace y1 = real(word("`lottery'", `j')) if x1 == `j'
}

* method2 

set seed 2803 
generate x2 = runiform()
generate y2 = cond(x2 <= 0.2, 6, cond(x2 <= 0.4, 9, cond(x2 <= 0.6, 4, cond(x2 <= 0.8, 32, 98))))

tab1 y?
```

I am assuming that you want **equal probabilities**, which is not explicit. The principle of setting the seed is crucial for reproducibility. As in @Pearly Spencer's answer, using a `local` macro is widely considered (much) better style.

To spell it out: in this answer the probabilities are equal, but the frequencies will fluctuate from sample to sample. In @Pearly’s answer the frequencies are guaranteed equal, given that 50 is a multiple of 5, and randomness is manifest only in the order in which they arrive. This answer is like tossing a die with five faces 50 times; @Pearly’s answer is like drawing from a deck of 50 cards with 5 distinct types.